# Select rows based on index range excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a random list of numbers and a lengthy Excel sheet. I'd like to select all rows that *don't* have a number from the list as the value of Column B.

For example, is this is my chart...

```
|A |B |
|n1|0 |
|n2|1 |
|n3|3 |
|n4|4 |
|n5|7 |
|n6|8 |
|n7|10|
|n8|11|
|n9|15|
```

... and my range list is `{0, 3, 7, 10, 11, 15}`, I'd like to delete all the rows that don't meet the criteria, resulting in this new table:

```
|A |B |
|n1|0 |
|n3|3 |
|n5|7 |
|n7|10|
|n8|11|
|n9|15|
```

I'm guessing it involved the `MATCH` and `RANGE` commands somehow, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to code in Excel...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a helper column using a formula like:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(B2,{0,3,7,10,11,15},0))
```

Then you can filter on either TRUE or FALSE as necessary depending if you want to select the rows to delete or keep respectively.

[image]